# Iterate through the list and remove the duplicate for a queue

Tags: java, list

I am working on a logic , on a list of type String.

All , I am looking for is removing the duplicate element in the list. I am little buzzed what going wrong. As it is comparing the same index level element.

```
List<Favorite> queueFavorites = retrieve();

// Removing the duplicate favorite
for (Iterator<Favorite> favoriteIterator = queueFavorites.iterator(); favoriteIterator.hasNext(); )
{
    FavoriteBO favoriteBO = favoriteIterator.next();
    if(duplicateCount(queueFavorites,favoriteBO) > 1)
    {
       favoriteIterator.remove();
       System.out.println("Favorite Removed : " + favoriteBO.getFavoriteUID());
    }
}
```

I have overridden Favorite class method like hashCode and equals. This means I need to make use of duplicateCount () method.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Why don't you create a `Set` from that `List`.

Comment: It wont work when I m overridding the equals and hascode of my List type. say my list is of type List<Favorite> instead of List<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` instead of `List` which stores only unique value and implement `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Set mySet = new HashSet(List);
To convert List to Set

Or else

Use contains method and remove the object if it is already present in List so that order is maintained

Comment: I cant because , It wont work when I m overridding the equals and hascode of my List type. say my list is of type List<Favorite> instead of List<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Java had Set for this kind of things....so you should populate a set instead of a list...but if is not your case and you have an external list you can create a Set impl (e.g. HashSet) giving your list in the constructor

Set noDups = new HashSet (yourList);

Et voilå

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the problem instead of using Set is to use a map:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Iterator<String> it = queueFavorites.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String str = (String) it.next();
        if(map.get(str) != null) {
            it.remove();
        }
        else {
            map.put(str, new Object());
        }

    }
```

This approach preserves your List elements and only removes the duplicates

Comment: Thanks,  It wont work when I m overridding the equals and hascode of my List type. say my list is of type List<Favorite> instead of List<String>.